# Can an object have more than one axes of rotation?

Tags: rotational-kinematics, rotation, geometry

A few answers I found say "no." Perhaps because the conditions for rotation around multiple axes have not been met. However, I have seen a couple of videos of objects spinning around both the x and y axis (or two perpendicular axis passing through the centre of the body). Thus it appears to be possible, and although some say the axes combine into one, I found no such thing. Certainly in 2D there's only one, but 3D seems to open up the possibility for numerous axes of rotations to exist (a combination of x, y, and z axes). Thus my question is, what is the limit to the number of rotational axes a 3D object can have at any given moment?

Comment: $1$ axis, that's it, see Euler's rotation theorem in [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_rotation_theorem#:~:text=In%20geometry%2C%20Euler's%20rotation%20theorem,runs%20through%20the%20fixed%20point.).

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/322200/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19201/2451 and links therein.

Comment: But Euler's rotation theorem assumes that a point remains fixed, what if no such point exists?

Comment: If there is an axis of rotation, any point on it is fixed. This point might be outside the body. So make a bigger body that includes a point on the axis. This body rotates around a single axis of rotation. So any part of it must also rotate around this axis.